# Angular reloads the whole app on navigating back (location.back)

Tags: angular, angular-router

I noticed that the location.back() is reloading the whole application in my StackBlitz.com tour of heroes application.

Why is this happening?

https://stackblitz.com/angular/qvvrbgrmmda?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhero-detail%2Fhero-detail.component.ts

Comment: Can you explain what *is not functioning well* means ?

Comment: It's working as desired .what do you expect it to do ,be specific ?

Answer (score 1):

Add

```
import {CommonModule, HashLocationStrategy, LocationStrategy} from '@angular/common';
```

and

```
  providers: [
    {
      provide: LocationStrategy,
      useClass:  HashLocationStrategy
    }
  ],
```

and

```
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
  // ...
```

in your app.module.ts

Now there is a `#` in your URL which prevents the app from loading a new instance of the whole application every time you navigate within the app. Before you ask, the only way to get rid of the # is by Server-Side-Rendering, for example with Angular Universal You would also need to use localstorage or a backend call for saving the app state, which is not a good practice. So just stick with #. For more info see https://stackoverflow.com/a/37031886/4125622

Comment: Thanks @Phil, still not working. When the 'go back' button is clicked, the page is not navigated to the previous page.  This is the official app by Angular.

Comment: It seems to work fine when I open the app in a full window. When running together with the source code on the left side, `location.back()` doesn't work and app doesn't navigate to the previous page.

Comment: It worked for me when I made the changes. How do you reproduce the bug?

Comment: Try to run the app with output on the right side open. When I run app in a full window things work fine but not when output window is open on the right side. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is caused by the split pane preview feature provided by StackBlitz; it's not an issue with the Angular tutorial. If you use the full window preview it doesn't happen. So click "Open in New Window" to avoid the issue.